# How to process deep FormData object through multiparty(intermideate files)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Client I have form with next structure:

```js
{
  id: [Number],
  imgs: [object FileList],
  title: [String],
  // ...
}
```

After transformation this object in FormData I send him on Server.
On Server I use multiparty without streaming process.
Example:
[handler code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aboDl.png)

In result I receive this console:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3btKq.png)

Files object is empty.
Then I tried to recurse:
[recurse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dNTY.png)
but it didn't solve my problem.

How I can processing this [objecty FileList] in multiparty?